# How do I add a span around the first x number of words in an element?

Tags: javascript, html, split, slice

I need to style the first 10 words of a paragraph a different colour (the content is dynamic so I can't just put a span in the HTML).
My solution is to use javascript and do this will all the instances of .overview__text. I'm able to get the alert of words but in my HTML it's not showing the span.
Can you please explain like I'm 5 what I'm doing wrong?
Also is this the best solution?

**HTML**

```
<div class="overview__text">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no quem ipsum adipisci cum, zril 
    molestiae 
    mius no, ludus omittantur ullamcorper et mel. Fabulas probatus 
    consectetuer quo cu, an patrioque assentior pro. Sint omittantur ad 
    eam, sale apeirian
    </p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const overviewText = $('.overview__text p');

overviewText.each(function () {
    const text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    const overviewTextLead = text.slice(0, 10);
    alert(overviewTextLead);
    if (text.length > 20) {
        overviewText.innerHTML = `<span class="highlighted"> ${overviewTextLead.join(' ')}</span> ${overviewText.slice(10)}`;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `overviewText` is a jQuery collection, not an `HTMLElement` - you can't set its `innerHTML`. Instead, call the `html()` method on it.

Also, after the span, to get the rest of the text, call `.slice(10)` on the (original) `text` instead:

```js
const overviewText = $('.overview__text p');

overviewText.each(function() {
  const text = $(this).text().split(' ');
  const overviewTextLead = text.slice(0, 10);
  alert(overviewTextLead);
  if (text.length > 20) {
    overviewText.html(`<span class="highlighted"> ${overviewTextLead.join(' ')}</span> ${text.slice(10).join(' ')}`);
  }
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview__text">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no quem ipsum adipisci cum, zril 
    molestiae 
    mius no, ludus omittantur ullamcorper et mel. Fabulas probatus 
    consectetuer quo cu, an patrioque assentior pro. Sint omittantur ad 
    eam, sale apeirian
    </p>
</div>
```

But this is a lot more complicated than it needs to be - you can achieve the same thing without jQuery, using a regular expression and `.replace`:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('.overview__text p');
p.innerHTML = p.textContent.replace(
  /^(\s+[\w,]+){10}/,
  `<span class="highlighted">$&</span>`
);
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="overview__text">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no quem ipsum adipisci cum, zril 
    molestiae 
    mius no, ludus omittantur ullamcorper et mel. Fabulas probatus 
    consectetuer quo cu, an patrioque assentior pro. Sint omittantur ad 
    eam, sale apeirian
    </p>
</div>
```